# Gson serializes with ” instead of " (sometimes and randomly)

Tags: android, serialization, gson, retrofit

I'm using `Retrofit` with `Gson` for communication with Backend APIs. I've an endpoint to refresh the access token and it needs the refresh token inside body like this (`POST` request):
`{"refreshToken":"eyJhbGci...."}`
Most of the time it works but sometimes the `Gson` acts very strange (or something else, I'm not sure about that). Sometimes It sends the body like this:
`{"refreshToken":"eyJhbGci....”}`
Last char of the serialized string is **`”`** instead of normal **`"`**. So because of this backend assumes that `”` is part of my refresh token and it returns an error that my refresh token is invalid. 
I've checked my request if I mistakenly added `”` by myself but this is not the case. So what is the problem?

Comment: It sounds unbelievably. Make sure your client does not modify the request body in the whole request chain (Gson seems to deal with `\u2028` (Line Separator) and `\u2029` (Paragraph Separator) when writing strings, but not `\u201D` (Right Double Quotation Mark), and terminates string literals using [ASCII quotation mark](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/ceae88bd6667f4263bbe02e6b3710b8a683906a2/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/stream/JsonWriter.java#L592)). Also, make sure no interceptors modify the request body in the Retrofit chain.

Comment: Additionally, do you encounter such a strange behavior for a specific request, refreshing the token, only?

Comment: @fluffy I've some interceptors but they aren't modify the request body (only editing the headers and checking some conditions on the response)

Comment: @fluffy, yes just in this request and only sometimes

Comment: Add a log before sending a request (1); implement a logging type adapter factory for Gson (2) to make sure the refresh token object does not look "weird" or Gson output is "weird"; add a logging interceptor for Retrofit (3) to make sure it gets modified on the client side (it's hard to believe that the server modifies it). I don't really believe Gson can corrupt the request though.

Comment: Do you use Microsoft Word or another word processor in your workflow? It might not be Gson doing this fix.

Comment: @fluffy thanks, i will try these workarounds.

Comment: @JesseWilson no I'm not

Comment: @SamanSattari Any news on reproducing the issue and grabbing some logs?

Comment: @fluffy I've tried 1 and the request data was ok, and also I've tried 3 (HttpLoggingInterceptor) and I saw that request was going with ” instead of ". So yeah this is a client side issue, but I can't figure out what is the problem